# How to add two Boxes in a Box in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk3

Im trying to get into one box in GTK+ 2 boxes. I will explain you what I tried. First I create 3 Boxes(1,2,3). Then I add box(2) into the first box(1) with gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box(1)), box(2), TRUE, TRUE, 0); After I want to add another box in box(1) with gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box(1)), box3, TRUE, TRUE, 0).

I think its working but in terminal it show's Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_pack: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == NULL' failed. I did not understand the error because a parent can have more then one child.

So how can I add 2 boxes in 1 box? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `box(1)` and `box(2)` are not valid variable names, do you mean `box1` and `box2`?

Comment: yes it was just to show you what I mean. Of course their names are box1, box2. But I used in the text Boxes(1,2,3) so I just kept the name.

Comment: Please show actual code, and use proper formatting (indent code lines by four spaces)

Answer (score 1):

For all guys who have this problem aswell. Here a short code to create 2 boxes in another box:

```
GtkWidget *box;
GtkWidget *box1;
GtkWidget *box2;

box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0); //change it to HORIZONTAL if need
box1 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
box2 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box),box1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box),box2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show(box1);
gtk_widget_show(box2);
gtk_widget_show(box);
```

Of course you have to add the other elements and add the box to a other container but I think its clear now for everyone who had problems or will have problems with it.